# How to change the user-profile.tpl.php file to a customized outline like Linkedin for Drupal 7?

Tags: theming, users

I'm using Drupal 7.9 for an internal website. I'm trying to customize the "user-profile.tpl.php" file so it shows the fields that I've customized in the "admin/config/people/accounts/fields" to be shown below:

<<>>image block on the left<<>>

"**Full Name**
Job Title/Position

Your Organization Name Here, INC
1234 Your Address Here
Long City Name, ST 12345

(P) 555-123-1234
(E) emailaddress@somecompany.com"

But I'm having an issue writing the PHP in the "user-profile.tpl.php" file (I didn't touch the user-profile-category.tpl.php or the user-profile-item.tpl.php files)

This is what I've coded, which obviously is printing everything out wrong.

```
<div class="profile" style="float:left; width:100%;">

<div class="profile-image" style="width:20%; float:left;">
    <?php if ($user_picture): ?>
      <div class="user-picture">
        <?php print $user_picture; ?>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<div class="profile-info" style="width:80%; float:left;">
    <h1><?php print render($user_profile['field_profile_full_name']) ?></h1>
    <p><?php print render($user_profile['field_profile_job_title']) ?></p>

    <h3><?php print render($user_profile['field_profile_organization']) ?></h3>
    <p><?php print render($user_profile['field_profile_address']) ?><p>
    <p><?php print render($user_profile['field_profile_city']) ?>, <?php print render($user_profile['field_profile_state']) ?> <?php print render($user_profile['field_profile_zip_code']) ?></p>

    <h3>(P)<?php print render($user_profile['field_profile_business_phone']) ?></h3>
    <h3>(E)<?php print render($user_profile['field_profile_e_mail_address']) ?></h3>

</div>

</div>
```

When it prints on the page, everything still has a bunch of page breaks and space in between the info. And the address line isn't included in one block, it puts it on a new line each item.

How do I write the code so I can get the format outlined above?

Comment: just use views module. in views you have more control over the UI without touching PHP or CSS

Comment: Thanks I created it as a block and put it on the user, and users/* pages only. I didn't think I could over-ride the users page since it was part of the template.

Comment: Now how do I get rid of the User Template information that is being printed onto the user's page? I tried to delete the information in the user-profile.tpl.php file, but it still printed the fields out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Adding style="display:none;" to the <div class="profile"> in the user-profile.tpl.php file seems to have fixed it.

Comment: why you created it as block? you can create page view and use the same url to point to user profile page

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize views module to achieve what are you looking for, with some CSS styles.

While using views you have two options view user information:

**Option 1:**

1. Create block view (Users)
2. Select user fields you want to display
3. Then add `Contextual filters` (User: Uid)
4. From the configuration page make sure to select `Provide default value`
5. Then from `Type` drop down menu select `User ID from logged in user`.
6. Then apply changes.
7. Save view.
8. Under Structure -> Blocks locate the new created view in `content region`
9. Configure the block to appear only on the user account page `user` and `users/*`
10. Then you need to clear the original drupal content in the user view account page by apply this custom module.

**Code:**

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items){
  $items['user/%user']['page callback'] = 'mymodule_user_view_page';
}

function mymodule_user_view_page() {
  return array();
}
```

**Option 2:**

1. Create page view (Users)
2. Apply steps 2-6 as **Option 1**
3. Add Path `user/%user` under `Page Settings`
4. Save view.

Comment: Your step #5, says to "Then from Type drop down menu select User ID from logged in user." That only allows the Information for the currently logged in user to show on a page that doesn't belong to that user. Say for instance I want to look up User X so I type in users/User-X. But the information that appears is my information because I'm the one logged in. I tried to change the Contextual Filter to "User ID from URL" but that didn't seem to work. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: @AmandaGray In your case you need to add another block in the same view and change **Type** to `User ID from URL` and make sure to locate the new block to on the following page `users/*`

Comment: Thank you Aboodred1! This works exactly how I want it to!

Comment: @AmandaGray Glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems working.

However there is a issue regarding this implementation.

**Users registered after creating this view block are not able to see any detail in My profile page.**

Only the users registered before creating this block view are able to see their profile page .