# Change to posting status from registers users to anonymous

Tags: nodes, users

I'm not a hard core Drupal programmer but I'm learning bits by bits by using services like this one. I'm building a question answer site and was wondering how do I make to where users can select to be anonymous, like a little module that when a check box to be anonymous is selected the username will be changed to anonymous. It will be same thing [as this one asked here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73184/how-to-change-the-user-profile-tpl-php-file-to-a-customized-outline-like-linkedi) but instead of posting as anonymous you will be logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You could a field to the contenty type, like a boolean (0 = Anonymous, 1 = normal user)
Then you can create a custom module with on hook_node_presave and, if the boolean value is "0" you set programmatically the owner to anonymous.

In this way you lose the "link" between node and author, so I suggest you to add in the content type something like a user reference to the "real" author of the node.